# Comparing Strings and Integers

Tags: python, string, integer, compare, equals

Why is it that `55 != "hello"` is `true` while `"hello" > 35` gives you an error since there are two different data types?

I tried seeing if leaving hello without quotes would help, but you get an error either way.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, in which language are you working

Comment: I am coding in python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-2-compare-string-and-int-why-do-lists-compare-as-greater-than-n